# How to find out whether my email account has been hijacked or spoofed?

Tags: email, spoofing

I have an old university email account that, according to my alma mater, can only receive emails and forward them to another email address. I cannot even log in there and/or change the password, there are no credentials (at least not available to me). Recently, I received an email which seems to be the automatic response of an info@xyz.com address ("thanks for your mail, we get back to you asap ..."). This response also contained the alleged original message which was a bitcoin spam message sent from my old university account to this info mail address. Now my questions are:

- is it possible that my university mail account has been hijacked?
- is it conceivable that my mail address simply is in a database and they used it to spoof the email?
- is it conceivable that none of this ever happened and the mail is simply an attempt to check if this account is active?

How can I find out what exactly happened?

Comment: It is entirely possible this had nothing to do with you except a spoofed "from" header in the email. It's easy to spoof without actually having to have access to the account and having a "valid" email address might defeat the crappiest of spam filters.

Comment: 1) Yes 2) Yes, but the responsibility is then on the receiver to identify the message as spoofed 3) Yes — none of these questions should be posted publicly because no one here will be able to resolve it for you. Contact the University IT dept and ask them to investigate: it’s their job.

Comment: Thanks, I'll forward the message to the IT support.

Comment: As Mokubai said, the "From" header in an email is not actually verified or secured in any way that I'm aware of. You can pretty much set that field to whatever you want as long as it's a valid email address. It's likely a technique to get around spam filters, especially if it comes back to you as a reply to an email that you "sent" originally, I would expect most email providers to let it through on the assumption that it's a conversation you're having. It sounds like your uni email is not a real email address anyway, and simply acts as an alias to forward to an actual mail server.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an old university email account that, according to my alma
> mater, can only receive emails and forward them to another email
> address. I cannot even log in there and/or change the password.

If you cannot log in, it is not worth trying to figure out what is going wrong.

Ask the University to delete the account, and tell friends, colleagues and associates what your new email address is.

Make sure you have top notch spam control in your new system to prevent spoofing. Spoofing cannot normally be tracked down.

That is the best way forward.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't give you much advice on re-gaining control of your Email account if it *has* been hijacked, but I can suggest a way of seeing if it's been compromised in the first place.

Sites like *[Have I been Pwned?](https://haveibeenpwned.com/)* check your email against a database of known data breaches, so if your email was found in any of those, it'll tell you which ones and, if I remember correctly, when the breach was.